# Error Installing mySQL on mac yosamite

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm getting the following error from the installer while trying to install mysql on mac yosamite.
"The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for further assistance"

Please see below for the steps:
1. Downloaded the dmg from: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
2. ran the package - followed the steps and towards the very end getting this error

Please see below the installer log:
Oct 19 12:41:05 Srikanths-MBP installd[963]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
Oct 19 12:41:21 Srikanths-MBP installd[963]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7fb13e253ad0 {NSFilePath=./postinstall, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64/mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64.pkg#mysql-startup-item.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.mysql.startupitem, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64.pkg”.} {
        NSFilePath = "./postinstall";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cmysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64.pkg\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64/mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64.pkg#mysql-startup-item.pkg";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.mysql.startupitem";
    }
Oct 19 12:41:21 Srikanths-MBP Installer[1168]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Oct 19 12:41:21 Srikanths-MBP Installer[1168]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Oct 19 12:41:21 Srikanths-MBP Installer[1168]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.

Please help ! as I'm new to DBs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the Startup item is causing the error. I removed it from preferences and the installation worked.

Comment: how did you remove the Startup Item from preferences

Comment: After accepting the license agreement choose Customised Install, then disabling the 'Startup' item (third in the list). It worked for me!

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this problem by choosing **"Customized Install"** after accepting the license agreement, then **disabling the 'Startup' item** (third in the list). I left the Preferences option checked. It might be something with folder permissions and having your users folder in a non-default location, as I currently have my users folder placed on a volume that is NOT the boot volume.

Answer (score 3):

When you start the package installation of MySQL 5.6.21 (latest release compatible with OSX 10.9), after accepting the various form, choose Ad Hoc installation and remove the panel from the installation preferences and Startup items. So it works =)

Comment: I am also experiencing this same issue and your solution did not resolve it.

Comment: This is the same solution as @georg and it works. I went to customize then unselected the startup item.